# LibGDX android drag body by finger without mouse joint

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

I'm trying to do a very simple game, air hockey. Since I'm not very familiar with any game engines and don't want to use any c++ for now, I'm using LibGDX and subsequently Box2d.
I found MouseJoint example [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-backend-android-livewallpaper/source/browse/gdx-backend-android-livewallpaper-example/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/box2d/Box2DTest.java?r=ba02aaf34a8ca07daa0c30493bab993067c652f9), but this is totally not what I need.
I also tried using setTransform on bodies but they stop colliding normally.

What I need is very similar to this game: [Cardboard Football Club](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.casualgamestore.cardboardfootballclub3dhd) but only in plain and simple 2d. I just need to drag my bat with finger and make it collide with the puck and walls. Is it possible with dynamic bodies after all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170087/move-body-to-a-specific-position-box2d