# Moving box2d body ball

Tags: ios, iphone, box2d, physics

How can I move body ball in box2d like a volleyball without accelerating or dumping (with a constant speed).

Do I need a special formula for this?

Comment: Box2d simulates gravity, if that's what you're asking.  `bodyDef.gravityScale`

Comment: But I need parabolic trajectory of body, is it possible to make it without gravity scale?

Comment: You will want to use the Box2D gravity simulation. And that actually will cause your volleyball to accelerate.

Answer (score 1):

In Box2D you [move an object with forces](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/16/understanding-box2d-applicable-forces/). You can apply impulses or a linear force.

You can apply a impulse doing:

```
myBody->ApplyForce( force, myBody->GetWorldCenter() );
```

Or a force by doing:

```
myBody->ApplyForce(force, myBody->GetWorldCenter());
```

Note than a force is a b2Vec that you can construct doing:

```
b2Vec force = b2Vec2(0,50);
```

This force will only push the body up.

If you need a parabolic trajectory then you can create a force that has the component x and y greater than 0:

```
b2Vec force = b2Vec2(50,50);
```

Then the physics engine will do the rest.

You can also move to a [specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170087/move-body-to-a-specific-position-box2d) although I dont advice you to do that.

If you want more information about forces [then follow this link](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/forces).

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I need to implement parabola trajectory, using linear velocity, I need always constant speed of body ball, thats why I cant use impulses or forces.

Comment: OK `b2Vec force = b2Vec2(50,50);` might help, but I need to move ball after collision with player and 50, 50 vector is not what I want.

Comment: Yes this tutorial is good but they work only with x coord but I need both x & y

Comment: You can try the values by trial and error or you can try to understand how forces relate to the mass. But you want something like this? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924640/calculate-box2d-impulse-for-a-certain-angle-of-impact

Comment: Do you mean that the body should move in a parabolic path, but it should move along that path at a constant speed? (which is quite difficult by the way...)

Comment: @iforce2d thats right, but not enough, I need to implement start speed after collision, like with bounce = 7, but after that my body moves very fast, and I can't catch him. Now I guess that I should use force to make start speed of a body, but I don't know an angle of my ball after collision with player. Thanks for reply.